# CSS Send div to bottom of other div; bottom:0 isn't working

Tags: css, html

I have one div; header, and another called headerimg containing an image. I'm trying to make the header image stick to the bottom of the header (horizontal line) when resizing the page. Here's my code:

```
.header{ 
float:right;
width:93%; 
height:100px;
padding-right:0px;
background-image:url('img/barhorizontal.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
postion:relative;
}   

.headerimg{
bottom:0;
postion:absolute;   
}

.headerimg img{
width:45%;
height:auto;    
}
```

But it doesn't work. Here's my website: [Click](http://nefas.nl/)

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `position`.

```
you have:  postion
change to: position
```

How to spot things like this? Open developer tools in your browser. In Chrome, at least, it shows a little yellow triangle next to it and has that line crossed out. You see the error "Unknown property name"

Comment: It worked, but now the logo is really small. If i change .headerimg width and height to 100%, it doesn't stick to the bottom anymore, could you take a look at [link](http://nefas.nl/) ?

Comment: Don't make the image width 45%. It will be 45% of the container width so if the container is small, of course it's gonna be small.